# undefined reference to `typeinfo and 'vtable

Tags: c++, g++, undefined, vtable, typeinfo

i'm currently working on a program that employs the user of virtual functions. I am using only one virtual function and have come across what seems to be a common problem with a common solution which I have tried but unfortunately to no success.

I originally had virtual void calcArea(); in BasicShape.h without any definition or designation as a pure virtual function. I changed it and added {} at the end (as suggested on another thread with a similar problem) but I still get the following error:

I input:

```
g++ BasicShape.h BasicShape.cpp circle.h circle.cpp Rectangle.h Rectangle.cpp driver.cpp -o Lab4
```

And then I get:

```
/tmp/ccf1Y4Br.o: In function `BasicShape::BasicShape()': circle.cpp:(.text._ZN10BasicShapeC2Ev[_ZN10BasicShapeC5Ev]+0xf): undefined reference to `vtable for BasicShape'
/tmp/ccf1Y4Br.o:(.rodata._ZTI6circle[_ZTI6circle]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for BasicShape'
/tmp/ccc7gjtH.o:(.rodata._ZTI9Rectangle[_ZTI9Rectangle]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for BasicShape'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any ideas?

This is the implementation file BasicShape.h:

```
#ifndef BASICSHAPE_H
#define BASICSHAPE_H

class BasicShape 
{
  protected: 
    double area;

  public:
    double getArea() const;
     virtual void calcArea();
};

#endif
```

The accompanying BasicShape.cpp file:

```
#include "BasicShape.h"

double BasicShape::getArea() const
{
  return area;
}

void BasicShape::calcArea()
{
}
```

circle.h:

```
#include "BasicShape.h"

#ifndef CIRCLE_H
#define CIRCLE_H

class circle : public BasicShape
{
  private:
    long centerX;
    long centerY;
    double radius;

  public:
    circle(long, long, double);
    long getCenterX() const;
    long getCenterY() const;
    virtual void calcArea();
};

#endif
```

circle.cpp:

```
#include "circle.h"

// constructor
circle::circle(long userIn, long userIn2, double userIn3)
{
  centerX = userIn;
  centerY = userIn2;
  radius = userIn3;
  calcArea();
}

// accesors
long circle::getCenterX() const
{
  return centerX;
}

long circle::getCenterY() const
{
  return centerY;
}

// virtual function
void circle::calcArea()
{
  area = (3.14159 * radius * radius);
}
```

Rectangle.h

```
#include "BasicShape.h"

#ifndef RECTANGLE_H
#define RECTANGLE_H

class Rectangle : public BasicShape
{
  private:
    long width;
    long length;

  public:
    Rectangle(long, long);
    long getWidth() const;
    long getLength() const;
    virtual void calcArea();
};

#endif
```

Rectangle.cpp:

```
#include "Rectangle.h"

// constructor
Rectangle::Rectangle(long userIn, long userIn2)
{
  width = userIn;
  length = userIn2;
  calcArea();
}

// accessors
long Rectangle::getWidth() const
{
  return width;
}

long Rectangle::getLength() const
{
  return length;
}

void Rectangle::calcArea()
{
  area = (length * width);
}
```

The driver program is incomplete, but irrelevant to my problem anyway (at least I think so).

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include "BasicShape.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include "circle.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{

  cout << "Testing the functionality and efficiency of the circle class...\n";
  // declare circle object and test accessors and area computation
  circle objCircle(8,8,4);
  assert(objCircle.getCenterX() == 8);
  assert(objCircle.getCenterY() == 8);
  assert(objCircle.getArea() == 50.26544);
  cout << "Circle object testing completed successfully\n";

  cout << "Testing the functionality and efficiency of the Rectangle class...\n";
  // declare rectangle object and test accessors and area computation  
  //Rectangle objRec();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: IMHO you should try to state your full question first (including error messages, what you expect etc) before scaring people off with the huge code files.

Comment: Yea it does look a little menacing now that I come to think of it o_o thx for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so apparently this all seems to be a compiler issue. This entire time I was using gedit as a text editor and g++ as a compiler, but when I switched over to code blocks it was working just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, as it was pointed out, you have not to compile headers. (Although you can, it is irrelevant here --- gcc will generate precompiled headers).

And more interesting: your example perfectly works here, GCC 4.6.3.

Also, sidenote: calcArea shouldn't be public

Comment: So you think it might be a problem exclusive to g++ (my compiler)?

Comment: @newwarrior21st: I think it's more likely you accidentally failed to mention some minor difference in your code or what you did to try to compile it.  (These files are all in the same directory, all saved, etc.?)

Comment: Well, it seems simply your compiler can't handle virtual function in constructor (which is bad thing by default). I'd suggest to modify your code as follows: make area volatile, initialise it in BasicShape() to -1; in all nested getArea() methods simply check whether area isn't cached at all (area == -1) and then recalculate this value. Something like `double circle::getArea() { if (-1 == area) calcArea(); return area; }`

Comment: A little fix to previous msg: `double circle::getArea() const { ... };` If you've made `area` volatile, then this piece of code will work fine. Simply, `area` isn't part of object's state, so it shouldn't matter whether we change it in const method :). When you've made such design change, you'll get some benefits: you'll need to calculate area only if you'll need to.

Comment: Well, when you declare some field volatile, you can modify it in const methods :) So, you can cache answer inside object (even const one)

Comment: MPogoda: I think you mean `mutable`, not `volatile`.

Answer (score 1):

You should not tryo to compile the headers:

> g++ BasicShape.cpp circle.cpp Rectangle.cpp driver.cpp -o Lab4

Comment: I just tried to compile it this way but im getting the same error

Comment: @billz: That won't cause a link error.  It just sometimes causes surprises about which function gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler needs at least one translation unit where a virtual member is defined outside the class definition for each polymorphic class. It will instantiate some internal data for the class (virtual function table, polymorphic typeinfo) only if there is such a translation unit.

(Disclaimer: At least that was the case when I last used it, long ago)

You could either use an out-of-class definition for the `BasicShape::calcArea` function or add a virtual (optionally even pure virtual) destructor to `BasicShape` and define it out-of-class. The best place would probably be the `BasicShape.cpp`file.

BTW: As others have pointed out, you typically should not pass header files as separate translation units to the compiler. This will do no harm (other than inflate your compilation time), but also no good.

Comment: You mean like this:

    void BasicShape::calcArea()
    {
    }

When I do that it gives me this:

    BasicShape.cpp:11:6: error: prototype for ‘void    BasicShape::calcArea()’ does not match any in class ‘BasicShape’
BasicShape.h:14:20: error: candidate is: virtual double BasicShape::calcArea()

Comment: Yes, as you did for the other classes. Just put it into the `.cpp` file instead of defining it inline inside the class definition.

Comment: It seems like it helps but the compiler responds with this:

BasicShape.cpp:11:6: error: prototype for ‘void BasicShape::calcArea()’ does not match any in class ‘BasicShape’
BasicShape.h:14:20: error: candidate is: virtual double BasicShape::calcArea()

Comment: @newwarrior21st read carefully, one is void type another is double type

Comment: Its suggesting a virtual function that returns a double even though I've written no such thing anywhere.

Comment: @newwarrior21st Check your class definition, maybe you have accidentally declared such a thing.